# how to get page content from any site using selenium?

Tags: selenium

Here is my code it return null value but is runs well in browser console

```
   import java.util.List; 
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class google {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");


       JavascriptExecutor js;
       js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       String scriptReturningString = ""; 
       String scriptResult = (String)js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText"); 
       System.out.println("Text Inside:"+scriptResult);        

    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not pretty clear why you want to get source of page. In addition WebDriver is aimed to perform testing via UI. To operate just HTTP request/response there are more appropriate libraries.

Answer (score 3):

```
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
webDriver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");
String content = webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
System.out.println(content);
```

This code gets page's content (not source code), stores it in variable **content** and then prints it in console.

If you want to get page's source code you should use `webDriver.getPageSource()` method.